# generalizing the pumping lemma for UNIX-style regular expressions

Tags: regular-language, pumping-lemma

Most UNIX regular expressions have, besides the usual `**`,`+`,`?*` operators a backslash operator where `\1,\2,...` match whatever's in the last parentheses, so for example `*L=(a*)b\1*` matches the (non regular) language `*a^n b a^n*`.

On one hand, this seems to be pretty powerful since you can create `(a*)b\1b\1` to match the language `*a^n b a^n b a^n*` which can't even be recognized by a stack automaton. On the other hand, I'm pretty sure `*a^n b^n*` cannot be expressed this way.

I have two questions:

1. Is there any literature on this family of languages (UNIX-y regular). In particular, is there a version of the pumping lemma for these?
2. Can someone prove, or disprove, that `*a^n b^n*` cannot be expressed this way?

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for

- Benjamin Carle and Paliath Narendran "On Extended Regular Expressions" *LNCS 5457*

  - [DOI:10.1007/978-3-642-00982-2_24](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-00982-2_24)
  - PDF Extended Abstract at http://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/docs/00/17/60/43/PDF/notes_on_extended_regexp.pdf
- C. Campeanu, K. Salomaa, S. Yu: A formal study of practical regular expressions, *International Journal of Foundations of Computer Science*, Vol.  14  (2003) 1007 - 1018.

  - [DOI:10.1142/S012905410300214X](http://dx.doi.org/10.1142/S012905410300214X)

and of course follow their citations forward and backward to find more literature on this subject.

Answer (score 0):

a^n b^n is CFL. The grammar is

```
A -> aAb | e
```

you can use pumping lemma for RL to prove A is not RL

Comment: Yup, "regular" expressions have been extended to recognize languages that finite state machines will not recognize.

Comment: this doesn't answer the question. he wants a statement of a theorem (similar to the pumping lemma) that he can use to prove what regular expressions can support when they support backreferences.

Comment: @ken. His original question is asking why a^n b^n is CFL and how to prove it is not a RL. And WhirlWind also noticed that. 

You can ask Avi and you can also report to the website admin about the untracked modified thread.

Comment: @ziang. He didn't. He asked you to prove whether a^n b^n can be recognized by **Extended** regexps which allow backreferences.

Answer (score -1):

Ruby 1.9.1 supports the following regex:

```
regex = %r{ (?<foo> a\g<foo>a | b\g<foo>b | c) }x

p regex.match("aaacbbb")
# the result is #<MatchData "c" foo:"c">
```

"[Fun with Ruby 1.9 Regular Expressions](http://pragdave.blogs.pragprog.com/pragdave/2008/10/fun-with-ruby-19-regular-expressions.html)" has an example where he actually arranges all the parts of a regex so that it looks like a context-free grammar as follows:

```
sentence = %r{ 
    (?<subject>   cat   | dog   | gerbil    ){0} 
    (?<verb>      eats  | drinks| generates ){0} 
    (?<object>    water | bones | PDFs      ){0} 
    (?<adjective> big   | small | smelly    ){0} 

    (?<opt_adj>   (\g<adjective>\s)?     ){0} 

    The\s\g<opt_adj>\g<subject>\s\g<verb>\s\g<opt_adj>\g<object> 
}x
```

I think this means that at least Ruby 1.9.1's regex engine, which is the Oniguruma regex engine, is actually equivalent to a context-free grammar, though the capturing groups aren't as useful as an actual parser-generator.

This means that "[Pumping lemma for context-free languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pumping_lemma_for_context-free_languages)" should describe the class of languages recognizable by Ruby 1.9.1's regex engine.

**EDIT:** Whoops! I messed up, and didn't do an important test which actually makes my answer above totally wrong. I won't delete the answer, because it's useful information  nonetheless.

```
regex = %r{\A(?<foo> a\g<foo>a | b\g<foo>b | c)\Z}x
#I added anchors for the beginning and end of the string
regex.match("aaacbbb")
#returns nil, indicating that no match is possible with recursive capturing groups.
```

**EDIT:** Coming back to this many months later, I just discovered that my test in the last edit was incorrect. `"aaacbbb"` shouldn't be expected to match `regex` even if `regex` does operate like a context-free grammar.

The correct test should be on a string like `"aabcbaa"`, and that does match the regex:

```
regex = %r{\A(?<foo> a\g<foo>a | b\g<foo>b | c)\Z}x
regex.match("aaacaaa")
# => #<MatchData "aaacaaa" foo:"aaacaaa">
regex.match("aacaa")
# => #<MatchData "aacaa" foo:"aacaa">
regex.match("aabcbaa")
# => #<MatchData "aabcbaa" foo:"aabcbaa">
```